# Use PayPal NVP API to send "Option 1 name" and similar values

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-nvp, nvp

When downloading PayPal payment history as a CSV, the data contains columns labeled, `"Option 1 Name," "Option 1 Value," "Option 2 Name," and "Option 2 Value."`

My application submits payments to PayPal through the `NVP API` (at endpoint https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp), using the `DoDirectPayment` method.

Using this API, is there a way to submit some name-value pairs that will allow me to insert `ad-hoc` values into the `"Option 1 Name," "Option 1 Value,"` columns mentioned above?

**Sources I've consulted:**

I believe the documentation is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried adding the following various name-value pairs to the request, an odd assortment to say the least. It's an odd assortment, I admit, as I was trying just about anything that might work from various online sources, most of them probably either outdated or for another Paypal API.

```
$params['option_name0'] = "foo";
$params['option_selection0'] = "bar";
$params['option_name_1'] = "foo";
$params['option_selection_1'] = "bar";
$params['on1'] = "foo";
$params['os1'] = "bar";
$params['on0'] = "foo";
$params['os0'] = "bar";
$params['on0_1'] = "foo";
$params['os0_1'] = "bar";
$params['option_select0'] = "foo";
$params['option_amount0'] = "bar";
$params['option_select1'] = "foo";
$params['option_amount1'] = "bar";
$params['L_NAME0'] = "L_NAME0";
$params['L_DESC0'] = "bar";
$params['L_NAME1'] = "L_NAME1";
$params['L_DESC1'] = "bar";
```

None of the above have succeeded in putting any values into these columns.
  So is this possible at all? And if not, what could these columns possibly be for?

Comment: Thansk for the edit, @Edvin!

Comment: No problem. :) Good luck since I don't know the answer.